# How to prove that a Markov chain is transient?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, markov-chains, random-walk

I have a Markov chain $\{Y_n: n\geqslant 0\}$ where the $Y_n$ are integer-valued.

The probability of going from any state $i$ to its right (i.e., from state $i$ to state $i+1$) is $p$,
and the probability of going from any state $i$ to its left (i. e., from state $i$ to state $i-1$) is $1-p$.

Now, I am examining various scenarios pertaining to classifying the states of this Markov chain, for different possible values of $p$.

I can see, by intuition, that for all values of $p$ where $p \ne 1/2$, the Markov chain is transient.  This is because when $p > 1/2$, there is a higher probability of moving to the right than to the left, for every state $i$.

This means, starting at $i$, the chain will progressively keep shifting to the right at every time step.  So, there is a positive probability that it will not return to $i$, when $p > 1/2$.

Similarly, when $p < 1/2$, starting from $i$, the chain will keep moving to the left at every time step.  So again there is a positive probability that it will not return to $i$, when $p < 1/2$.

But I want to be more precise and mathematical when I am proving this property, and not rely on these somewhat informal statements.  I'd be grateful for any insight on how to actually prove this.

Comment: What is $Y_1$? Is there a state to its left or does the chain stay at $Y_1$ with probability $1-q$? Also, please try to use MathJax when writing up math statements.

Comment: I replaced $q$ with $p$ in the question since in this context, often is written $q=1-p$ where $p$ is the probability of a transition to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N_0 = \inf\{n>0:Y_n=0\mid Y_n=0\}$ be the time until the first return to zero. Let $u_n = \mathbb P(Y_n=0)$ (conditioned on $Y_0=0$) and $t_n=\mathbb P(N_0=n)$. Then $u_0=1$ and $t_0=0$. For $n\geqslant 1$, conditioning on $N_0$ yields
\begin{align}
u_n &= \mathbb P(Y_n=0)\\
&= \mathbb E[\mathbb P(S_n=0\mid N_0)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb P(S_n=0\mid N_0=k)\mathbb P(N_0=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n u_{n-k} t_k.
\end{align}

Let $F(s)=\mathbb E[s^{Y_n}]$ be the probability generating function of $N_0$ and $G$ the generating function of the sequence $\{u_n\}$. Then (using Tonelli's theorem to interchange the order of summation):
\begin{align}
G(s) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty u_ns^n\\
&= 1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n u_{n-k}t_k s^n\\
&= 1 + \sum_{k=0}^\infty u_k z^k\sum_{n=k}^\infty t_{n-k} s^{n-k}\\
&= 1 + F(s)G(s),
\end{align}
and thus $F(s) = 1-\frac1{G(s)}$. Note that $S_n=0$ precisely when $n=2m$ is even and the number of upward and downward steps are equal. Hence, $q_{2m} = \binom{2m}m(p(1-p))^m$ and the generalised binomial theorem yields
\begin{align}
G(s) &= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom{2m}m(p(1-p))^m s^{2m}\\ 
&= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}m (-1)^m4^m (p(1-p))^m s^{2m}\\
&= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}m  (-1)^{-1/2-m} (-(4p(1-p)s^2))^m\\
&= \frac1{\sqrt{1-4p(1-p)s^2}},
\end{align}
and thus $F(s) = 1-\sqrt{1-4p(1-p)s^2}$.

It follows that
$$\mathbb P(N_0<\infty) = F(1) = 1 - \sqrt{1-4p(1-p)}<1,$$
and hence the chain is transient.

Note that if $p=\frac12$ then $F(s)=1-\sqrt{1-s^2}$, so $\mathbb P(N_0<\infty)=1$, but

$$
F'(s) = \frac s{\sqrt{1-s^2}} \stackrel{s\to 1}\longrightarrow \infty,
$$
so that $N_0$ has infinite expectation (in this case we say that the chain is *null recurrent*).

Comment: I am trying to understand and work out the above steps - thank you for the insight.  I was also wondering:  is it possible to use the law of large numbers and make an argument here that X_1 + X_2 + ... +X_n do not add to 0 when p is not 1/2 (here, each X_i can be either 1 or -1, representing a shift either to the right or left of state i).  Therefore, X_1 + X_2 + ... also do not add to 0 when n tends to infinity?

Comment: I am now working out the calculation behind the generating function F(s).  But I think I am stuck here.  I have calculated moment generating functions but here we have E(s^N0).  Will this be summation (over all possible values of N0) of (s^N0) * pdf of N0?  Thank you once again.

Comment: @probstudent In general, given a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}$, the associated *generating function* is the (formal) power series $s\mapsto\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ns^n$. If the sequence $\{a_n\}$ corresponds to the probability mass function of a nonnegative integer-valued random variable, it is called a *probability generating function.* (The coefficient of $s^n$ is the probability that the random variable takes value $n$.)